# How to reliably detect RICHTEXT format on clipboard?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-10.1-berlin, richtext

Embarcadero RAD Studio VCL has the `TClipboard.HasFormat` Method, with a usage e.g. `Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT)` or `Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_BITMAP)` etc..

But I did not find any supported `CF_RTF` or `CF_RICHTEXT` format-descriptor which indicates a rich-text format in the clipboard.

So I created some formatted text in Microsoft WordPad and copied it to the clipboard. Then I used a clipboard-spy program to inspect the formats on the clipboard:

[image]

This lists 3 RichText formats with the format-descriptors **C078**, **C16B** and **C1A5**.

Are these format-descriptors universal or dependent from the individual system or from the current situation? I.e., can I generally use `Clipboard.HasFormat($C078)` to detect any RichText format on the clipboard? Or is there another method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I generally use `Clipboard.HasFormat($C078)` to detect any
>   RichText format on the clipboard?

No, You need to register the RTF clipboard format via [`RegisterClipboardFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049(v=vs.85).aspx) function. The returned value is generated by the system and may vary.

> Registers a new clipboard format. This format can then be used as a
>   valid clipboard format.
>
> If a registered format with the specified name already exists, a new
>   format is not registered and the return value identifies the existing
>   format. This enables more than one application to copy and paste data
>   using the same registered clipboard format.

```
var
  CF_RTF: UINT;
...
initialization
  CF_RTF := RegisterClipboardFormat('Rich Text Format');
```

Then check for:

```
if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_RTF) then ...
{ or // if Windows.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_RTF) then ... }
```

---

Edit: After reading the documentation: [`How to Use Rich Edit Clipboard Operations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270402.aspx)

The constant `CF_RTF` is already declared in `RichEdit` unit as:

```
CF_RTF                 = 'Rich Text Format';
CF_RTFNOOBJS           = 'Rich Text Format Without Objects'; 
CF_RETEXTOBJ           = 'RichEdit Text and Objects';
```

So it might be a better idea to use other naming for the returned value of `RegisterClipboardFormat`. e.g.

```
uses RichEdit;
...
var
  CF_RICHTEXT: UINT;
...
initialization
  CF_RICHTEXT := RegisterClipboardFormat(RichEdit.CF_RTF);
```

And:

```
if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_RICHTEXT) then ...
```

Note: There are already a few *reserved* system clipboard formats such as `CF_TEXT` (=1), `CF_BITMAP`(=2) etc ... but the "CF_RTF" or "CF_RICHTEXT" is not one of them. it is a custom format used by the `RICHEDIT` common control, and registered via `RegisterClipboardFormat` as already mentioned.

Comment: I have done exactly this because it is recommended on many websites. Then I copied again the formatted text from WordPad to the clipboard. But the clipboard spy program does not list any `CF_RTF` format.

Comment: @user, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. do you mean that clipboard spy do not explicitly show "CF_RTF" as description? if that is the case you could name your variable "`CF_RICHTEXT`" or whatever, it does not matter. the format identifier is a string anyway i.e. `Rich Text Format`. as opposed to `CF_BITMAP` which is a system const (2). `CF_RTF` is a *custom* format.

Comment: So is the string 'Rich Text Format' a system constant? Otherwise, the clipboard couldn't recognize it at as an identifier for RichText?

Comment: @user, "Rich Text Format" is the common way `RICHEDIT` controls copy RTF data to the clipboard. The control first registers this format in the system via `RegisterClipboardFormat`. please read the remarks from the documentation.

Comment: This is all documented, @user, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270402.aspx It's really important that you learn to read documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why do you always delete my comments and downgrade my votings? Is this funny for you?

Comment: @user I can't delete comments.