# Injecting RTF code in the Clipboard to paste into MS Word as RTF text via a VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard, rtf

I've been looking for a while now and cannot seem to get a solution to do the following:

1. Enter some RTF code into the Clipboard (e.g. `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252 TEST\sub 0\f1\lang1033\_\f2\lang18441 1\nosupersub\par}`, which includes TEST0-1 in the desired format
2. Paste the clipboard content into word file at the selected selection.

I have tried the following:

```
Sub testpastertf()
    Dim strSelection As String
    
    strSelection = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252 TEST\sub 0\f1\lang1033\_\f2\lang18441 1\nosupersub\par}"
    
    Set MyData = New DataObject

    MyData.SetText strSelection
    MyData.PutInClipboard
    
'Test1
    Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    Selection.TypeParagraph
'Test 2
    Selection.PasteAndFormat wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery
    Selection.TypeParagraph
'Test 3
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, Placement:= _
        wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the initial two tests do not work as text is only pasted as "plain text" which is essentially the RTF code and the last one throws an error
[image: Error message returned]

I have found some sites with code which I believe would work, but I must be missing something as I am not able to get the explanations shown to work:

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/258513/how-to-paste-a-rich-text-format-string-into-word-with-visual-basic-aut (In all likelihood this does not work as it provides code for a VBA-based application)
2. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=977792 (missing file "Oopic_5.1.22/Source/modClipboard.bas" linked in that post).

I presume what I want to do is possible, but I have no idea how to make this work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard shows how to use Windows API to put text on the clipboard.  Unfortunately it seems there's no pre-defined "RTF" for mat but you could try using the discussion here to address that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837425/how-to-reliably-detect-richtext-format-on-clipboard

Comment: ...or this looks like it does what you want   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev

Comment: Just tested that last link - the `Test2` test Sub included on that page is exactly what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer from slightly snarky and his pointing me to this posts:

1. [the code by Leigh Webber that @TimWilliams references](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev)
2. [Text To Clipboard in VBA Windows 10 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue)

I was able to piece together a working version of the code after a few modifications.

In brief, here are the contents for the different classes and modules to prepare the working code. **This works well for pasting RTF and HTLM elements**

The test code can be found below:

1. Class vbaClipboard (vbaClipboard.cls)

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "vbaClipboard"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
'Code edited from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev
'Moved to VB7 64 bit support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue

'Code edited from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev
'Moved to VB7 64 bit support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue

Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
    'NOTE: These declarations are not provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardFormatName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClipboardFormatNameA" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    'Note that we do not use the GetClipboardDataA declaration
    'Public Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" Alias "GetClipboardDataA" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipBoardData Lib "user32" Alias "GetClipboardData" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    'NOTE: the lstrCpy declaration you get from the VB6 API Viewer is WRONG. It's version is this:
    'Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As String) As Long
    'the code from this thread, use:
    'Private Declare Function lstrCpy Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
    'Replacing with that used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue
    Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
    'NOTE: These declarations are not provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue
    Private Declare Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardFormatName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClipboardFormatNameA" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)        'Use for hwnd
Private Const NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 1024

Private Const APINULL = 0

Private Const CF_TEXT = 1        'Text format. Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF) combination. A null character signals the end of the data. Use this format for ANSI text.

Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2        'A handle to a bitmap (HBITMAP).

Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3        'Handle to a metafile picture format as defined by the METAFILEPICT structure. When passing a CF_METAFILEPICT handle by means of DDE, the application responsible for deleting hMem should also free the metafile referred to by the CF_METAFILEPICT handle.

Private Const CF_SYLK = 4        'Microsoft Symbolic Link (SYLK) format.

Private Const CF_TIFF = 6        'Tagged-image file format.

Private Const CF_DIF = 5        'Software Arts' Data Interchange Format.

Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7        'Text format containing characters in the OEM character set. Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF) combination. A null character signals the end of the data.

Private Const CF_DIB = 8        'A memory object containing a BITMAPINFO structure followed by the bitmap bits.

Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9        'Handle to a color palette. Whenever an application places data in the clipboard that depends on or assumes a color palette, it should place the palette on the clipboard as well.

Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10        'Data for the pen extensions to the Microsoft Windows for Pen Computing.

Private Const CF_RIFF = 11        'Represents audio data more complex than can be represented in a CF_WAVE standard wave format.

Private Const CF_WAVE = 12        'Represents audio data in one of the standard wave formats, such as 11 kHz or 22 kHz PCM.

Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13        'Unicode text format. Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF) combination. A null character signals the end of the data.

Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14        'A handle to an enhanced metafile (HENHMETAFILE).

Private Const CF_HDROP = 15        'A handle to type HDROP that identifies a list of files. An application can retrieve information about the files by passing the handle to the DragQueryFile function.

Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16        'The data is a handle to the locale identifier associated with text in the clipboard. When you close the clipboard, if it contains CF_TEXT data but no CF_LOCALE data, the system automatically sets the CF_LOCALE format to the current input language. You can use the CF_LOCALE format to associate a different locale with the clipboard text.

Private Const CF_DIBV5 = 17        'A memory object containing a BITMAPV5HEADER structure followed by the bitmap color space information and the bitmap bits.

Private Const CF_DSPBITMAP = &H82        'Bitmap display format associated with a private format. The hMem parameter must be a handle to data that can be displayed in bitmap format in lieu of the privately formatted data.

Private Const CF_DSPENHMETAFILE = &H8E        'Enhanced metafile display format associated with a private format. The hMem parameter must be a handle to data that can be displayed in enhanced metafile format in lieu of the privately formatted data.

Private Const CF_DSPMETAFILEPICT = &H83        'Metafile-picture display format associated with a private format. The hMem parameter must be a handle to data that can be displayed in metafile-picture format in lieu of the privately formatted data.

Private Const CF_DSPTEXT = &H81        'Text display format associated with a private format. The hMem parameter must be a handle to data that can be displayed in text format in lieu of the privately formatted data.

Private Const CF_GDIOBJFIRST = &H300        'Start of a range of integer values for application-defined GDI object clipboard formats. The end of the range is CF_GDIOBJLAST.

Private Const CF_GDIOBJLAST = &H3FF        'See CF_GDIOBJFIRST.

Private Const CF_OWNERDISPLAY = &H80        'Owner-display format. The clipboard owner must display and update the clipboard viewer window, and receive the WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME, WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD, WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD, WM_SIZECLIPBOARD, and WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD messages. The hMem parameter must be NULL.

Private Const CF_PRIVATEFIRST = &H200        'Start of a range of integer values for private clipboard formats. The range ends with CF_PRIVATELAST. Handles associated with private clipboard formats are not freed automatically; the clipboard owner must free such handles, typically in response to the WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD message.
Private Const CF_PRIVATELAST = &H2FF        'See CF_PRIVATEFIRST.

Public Property Get ClipboardFormatsAvailable() As Collection

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    #If VBA7 Then 'Note: Adding this to support 64Bit
        Dim thisClipboardFormat As LongPtr
        Dim returnStringLength As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim thisClipboardFormat As Long
        Dim returnStringLength As Long
    #End If

    Dim myCFAvailable As New Collection
    Dim clipBoardFormatName As String
    Dim clipboardFormat As clipboardFormat
    Dim success As Boolean
    
    success = OpenClipboard(0)
    If success Then
        thisClipboardFormat = 0
        thisClipboardFormat = EnumClipboardFormats(thisClipboardFormat)
        While thisClipboardFormat <> 0
            Set clipboardFormat = New clipboardFormat
            clipBoardFormatName = String$(NAME_MAX_LENGTH, vbNullChar)
            returnStringLength = GetClipboardFormatName(thisClipboardFormat, _
            clipBoardFormatName, Len(clipBoardFormatName))
            clipBoardFormatName = TrimNull(clipBoardFormatName)
            If clipBoardFormatName = "" Then
                clipBoardFormatName = BuiltInClipboardFormatName(CLngPtr(thisClipboardFormat)) 'Adding CLng() to suport 64Bit
            End If
            clipboardFormat.Name = clipBoardFormatName
            clipboardFormat.Number = CLng(thisClipboardFormat) 'Adding CLng() to suport 64Bit
            myCFAvailable.Add clipboardFormat, clipboardFormat.Name
            thisClipboardFormat = EnumClipboardFormats(thisClipboardFormat)
        Wend
        Set ClipboardFormatsAvailable = myCFAvailable
        CloseClipboard
    Else
        Set ClipboardFormatsAvailable = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Property
ErrorHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    CloseClipboard
End Property

Public Function GetClipboardText(ByVal aClipboardFormatNumber As Long) As String
    'Do not handle errors - let them bubble up
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim lpMemory As LongPtr
        Dim hMemory As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lpMemory As Long
        Dim hMemory As Long
    #End If
    
    Dim wLen As Integer
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    Dim haveMemoryLocked As Boolean
    Dim wClipAvail As Integer
    Dim szText As String
    Dim wSize As Long
    Dim clipBoardText As String
    
    clipBoardText = ""
    'Before accessing the clipboard, find out if the requested format is available
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(aClipboardFormatNumber) = APINULL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Requested clipboard format number " & aClipboardFormatNumber & " Is Not available On the clipboard."
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim success As Boolean
    success = OpenClipboard(0)
    If success Then
        'Get a handle to a memory structure containing the clipboard data in the requested format
        hMemory = GetClipboardData(aClipboardFormatNumber)
        CloseClipboard
        'If the handle is null, something went wrong
        If hMemory = APINULL Then
            'Throw an error
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To retrieve data from the Clipboard."
        End If
        'The handle is good. How much data came back
        wSize = GlobalSize(hMemory)
        'Fill our destination string with nulls
        clipBoardText = Space(wSize)
        'Lock the memory
        'Get a pointer to the locked memory area
        lpMemory = GlobalLock(hMemory)
        If lpMemory = APINULL Then
            'CloseClipboard
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To lock clipboard memory."
        End If
        ' Copy the locked memory into our string
        RetVal = lstrcpy(clipBoardText, lpMemory)
        'Unlock memory
        GlobalUnlock hMemory
        ' Get rid of trailing stuff.
        clipBoardText = Trim(clipBoardText)
        GetClipboardText = TrimNull(clipBoardText)
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To open Clipboard. Perhaps some other application Is using it."
    End If
End Function

Public Sub SetClipboardText(ByVal aText As String, ByVal aClipboardFormatName As String)
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim lpMemory As LongPtr
        Dim hMemory As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lpMemory As Long
        Dim hMemory As Long
    #End If
    
    Dim wLen As Long 'Changing from Integer to Long as geting Overflow error
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    Dim memoryIsLocked As Boolean
    Dim memoryIsAllocated As Boolean
    Dim clipBoardIsOpen As Boolean
    
    memoryIsAllocated = False
    memoryIsLocked = False
    clipBoardIsOpen = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Select Case aClipboardFormatName
        Case "HTML Format"
            aText = addHTMLWraper(aText)
    End Select
    
    ' Get the length, including one extra for a CHR$(0) at the end.
    wLen = Len(aText) + 1
    'Add a null to the end
    aText = aText & Chr$(0)
    'Allocate some memory
    hMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, wLen + 1)
    If hMemory = APINULL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1001, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To allocate memory."
    Else
        memoryIsAllocated = True
    End If
    lpMemory = GlobalLock(hMemory)
    If lpMemory = APINULL Then
        'Throw an error
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1001, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To lock memory."
    Else
        memoryIsLocked = True
    End If
    ' Copy our string into the locked memory.
    RetVal = lstrcpy(lpMemory, aText)
    ' Don't send clipboard locked memory.
    RetVal = GlobalUnlock(hMemory)
    'If the preceding throws an error, it will be handled in ErrorHandler
    memoryIsLocked = True
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = APINULL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To open Clipboard. Perhaps some other application Is using it."
    Else
        clipBoardIsOpen = True
    End If
    'Is the requested format one of the Windows built-in formats
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim thisClipboardFormatNumber As Long
    thisClipboardFormatNumber = BuiltInClipboardFormatNumber(aClipboardFormatName)
    If thisClipboardFormatNumber = 0 Then
        'Nope. Register the format
        On Error Resume Next
        thisClipboardFormatNumber = CLng(RegisterClipboardFormat(aClipboardFormatName)) 'Note: Adding this to support 64Bit
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To register clipboard format: " & aClipboardFormatName & _
            ". Error message: " & Err.description
        End If
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        If thisClipboardFormatNumber = 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To register clipboard format: " & aClipboardFormatName
        End If
    End If
    'Empty the clipboard
    If EmptyClipboard() = APINULL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To Empty the clipboard."
    End If
    If SetClipboardData(thisClipboardFormatNumber, hMemory) = APINULL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", "Unable To Set the clipboard data."
    End If
    CloseClipboard
    GlobalFree hMemory
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Dim description As String
    description = Err.description
    On Error Resume Next
    If memoryIsLocked Then GlobalUnlock hMemory
    If memoryIsAllocated Then GlobalFree hMemory
    If clipBoardIsOpen Then CloseClipboard
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "vbaClipboard", description
End Sub

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal aString As String) As String
    Dim nullAt As Long
    nullAt = InStr(1, aString, vbNullChar)
    If nullAt > 0 Then
        TrimNull = Left(aString, _
            nullAt - 1)
    Else
        TrimNull = aString
    End If
End Function

Private Function BuiltInClipboardFormatNumber(ByVal aClipboardFormatName As String) As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Select Case UCase(aClipboardFormatName)
        Case "CF_TEXT"
            result = 1
        Case "CF_BITMAP"
            result = 2
        Case "CF_METAFILEPICT"
            result = 3
        Case "CF_SYLK"
            result = 4
        Case "CF_DIF"
            result = 5
        Case "CF_TIFF"
            result = 6
        Case "CF_OEMTEXT"
            result = 7
        Case "CF_DIB"
            result = 8
        Case "CF_PALETTE"
            result = 9
        Case "CF_PENDATA"
            result = 10
        Case "CF_RIFF"
            result = 11
        Case "CF_WAVE"
            result = 12
        Case "CF_UNICODETEXT"
            result = 13
        Case "CF_ENHMETAFILE"
            result = 14
        Case "CF_HDROP"
            result = 15
        Case "CF_LOCALE"
            result = 16
        Case "CF_DIBV5"
            result = 17
        Case "CF_DSPBITMAP"
            result = &H82
        Case "CF_DSPENHMETAFILE"
            result = &H8E
        Case "CF_DSPMETAFILEPICT"
            result = &H83
        Case "CF_DSPTEXT"
            result = &H81
        Case "CF_GDIOBJFIRST"
            result = &H300
        Case "CF_GDIOBJLAST"
            result = &H3FF
        Case "CF_OWNERDISPLAY"
            result = &H80
        Case "CF_PRIVATEFIRST"
            result = &H200
        Case "CF_PRIVATELAST"
            result = &H2FF
        Case Else
            result = 0
    End Select
    BuiltInClipboardFormatNumber = result
End Function

Private Function BuiltInClipboardFormatName(ByVal aIndex As LongPtr) As String 'Note: Adding LongPtr this to support 64Bit
    Dim n As String
    Select Case aIndex
        Case 1
            n = "CF_TEXT"
        Case 2
            n = "CF_BITMAP"
        Case 3
            n = "CF_METAFILEPICT"
        Case 4
            n = "CF_SYLK"
        Case 5
            n = "CF_DIF"
        Case 6
            n = "CF_TIFF"
        Case 7
            n = "CF_OEMTEXT"
        Case 8
            n = "CF_DIB"
        Case 9
            n = "CF_PALETTE"
        Case 10
            n = "CF_PENDATA"
        Case 11
            n = "CF_RIFF"
        Case 12
            n = "CF_WAVE"
        Case 13
            n = "CF_UNICODETEXT"
        Case 14
            n = "CF_ENHMETAFILE"
        Case 15
            n = "CF_HDROP"
        Case 16
            n = "CF_LOCALE"
        Case 17
            n = "CF_DIBV5"
        Case &H82
            n = "CF_DSPBITMAP"
        Case &H8E
            n = "CF_DSPENHMETAFILE"
        Case &H83
            n = "CF_DSPMETAFILEPICT"
        Case &H81
            n = "CF_DSPTEXT"
        Case &H300
            n = "CF_GDIOBJFIRST"
        Case &H3FF
            n = "CF_GDIOBJLAST"
        Case &H80
            n = "CF_OWNERDISPLAY"
        Case &H200
            n = "CF_PRIVATEFIRST"
        Case &H2FF
            n = "CF_PRIVATELAST"
    End Select
    BuiltInClipboardFormatName = n
End Function

Private Function addHTMLWraper(ByVal sHtmlElement As String) As String
    Dim sData As String
    Const sContextStart = "<HTML><BODY><!--StartFragment -->"
    Const sContextEnd = "<!--EndFragment --></BODY></HTML>"
    Const sHtmlHeader = _
            "Version:1.0" & vbCrLf & _
            "StartHTML:<{]aaaaaaa" & vbCrLf & _
            "EndHTML:<{]bbbbbbb" & vbCrLf & _
            "StartFragment:<{]ccccccc" & vbCrLf & _
            "EndFragment:<{]dddddddd" + vbCrLf
    sData = sHtmlHeader & sContextStart & sHtmlElement & sContextEnd
    sData = Replace(sData, "<{]aaaaaaa", Format(Len(sHtmlHeader), "0000000000"))
    sData = Replace(sData, "<{]bbbbbbb", Format(Len(sData), "0000000000"))
    sData = Replace(sData, "<{]ccccccc", Format(Len(sHtmlHeader & sContextStart), "0000000000"))
    sData = Replace(sData, "<{]ddddddd", Format(Len(sHtmlHeader & sContextStart & sHtmlElement), "0000000000"))
    addHTMLWraper = sData
End Function
```

2. Code for Class ClipboardFormat(ClipboardFormat.cls)

```
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ClipboardFormat"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

Private mNumber As Long
Private mName As String

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = mNumber
End Property
Public Property Let Number(ByVal value As Long)
    mNumber = value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    mName = value
End Property
```

3. Code for testing module

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    'This routine tests the vbaClipboard object.
    'Before running this, copy some text from Word. This will place Rich Text Format data
    'on the clipboard. The test will preserve the RTF data, then use the clipboard
    'to manipulate some plain text ("CF_TEXT"). Finally, the test will put the
    'RTF data back on the clipboard. When the test is finished, you should be able
    'to go back into Word and hit Ctrl+V and paste your original copied text (with formatting).
    
    'Instantiate a vbaClipboard object
    Dim myClipboard As New vbaClipboard
    
    'The ClipboardFormat class encapsulates a clipboard format number and a name
    Dim clipboardFormat As clipboardFormat
    
    'Handle errors below
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    'Show the currently available formats
    'The ClipboardFormatsAvailable property returns a collection of ClipboardFormat objects
    'representing all formats currently available on the clipboard.
    
    Debug.Print "===================================================================="
    
    For Each clipboardFormat In myClipboard.ClipboardFormatsAvailable
        Debug.Print clipboardFormat.Number, clipboardFormat.Name
    Next clipboardFormat
    
    'Preserve the RTF currently on the clipboard (you did copy some, right?)
    Dim oldRTF As String
    'Get the format number value for Rich Text Format
    Dim richTextFormatNumber As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    richTextFormatNumber = myClipboard.ClipboardFormatsAvailable("Rich Text Format").Number
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "The clipboard does Not have any Rich Text Format data."
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    'Get the RTF data from the clipboard
    oldRTF = myClipboard.GetClipboardText(richTextFormatNumber)
    'Debug.Print oldRTF
    
    'Use the clipboard for something else
    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello, world!"
    myClipboard.SetClipboardText s, "CF_TEXT"
    
    'Get it back again
    Debug.Print myClipboard.GetClipboardText(1)
    
    'Show the currently available formats
    Debug.Print "===================================================================="
    For Each clipboardFormat In myClipboard.ClipboardFormatsAvailable
        Debug.Print clipboardFormat.Number, clipboardFormat.Name
    Next clipboardFormat
    
    'Now put back the RTF
    myClipboard.SetClipboardText oldRTF, "Rich Text Format"
    
    'Show the currently available formats
    Debug.Print "===================================================================="
    For Each clipboardFormat In myClipboard.ClipboardFormatsAvailable
        Debug.Print clipboardFormat.Number, clipboardFormat.Name
    Next clipboardFormat
    'You can now paste back into Word, and you'll get whatever text you selected
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.description
End Sub
Sub test2()
    'This tests stuffs some formatted text (RTF) onto the clipboard. Run the test, then
    'go into word and hit Ctrl+V to paste it in.
    Dim myClipboard As New vbaClipboard
    Dim text As String
    text = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab720{\fonttbl" & _
           "{\f0\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\froman\fcharset2 Symbol;}" & _
           "{\f2\froman\fprq2 Times New Roman;}}" & _
           "{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}" & _
           "\deflang1033\horzdoc{\*\fchars }{\*\lchars }" & _
           "\pard\plain\f2\fs24 This Is some \plain\f2\fs24\cf1" & _
           "formatted\plain\f2\fs24  text. }"
    
    myClipboard.SetClipboardText text, "Rich Text Format"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, Placement:= _
        wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Selection.TypeParagraph

    'Testing with HTML
    text = "<i>" & text & "</i>"
    myClipboard.SetClipboardText text, "HTML Format"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteHTML, Placement:= _
        wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice - I had tried with HTML, but gave up too quickly: this looks to be a useful addition...

Comment: This works well, although doesn't seem to support unicode special characters. I've tried modifying the code and using some other similar VBA clipboard classes, but no luck yet. MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format) seems to indicate the clipboard uses UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would probably use [the code by Leigh Webber that @TimWilliams references](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev), as long as you also include the updates for 64-bit VBA7 provided by someone else in that thread.

However, I believe you can do this just using the DataObject. It's just that I haven't tested this thoroughly.

The problems are

a. Word needs to see a data type called "Rich Text Format" in the clipboard. You can make sure there is a format with that name by passing the name to PutInClipBoard

b. If you just pass strSelection to PutInClipBoard, it is actually in the wrong format because VBA strings are 16-bit Unicode strings. So if you try to paste that in WOrd, you just see the RTF, more or less with a lot of extra "_" characters in there). You can fix that by converting the string into a Byte array instead. However, you also need to ensure that it is 0-terminated, otherwise Word will retrieve more stuff from the clipboard than it should.

So you seem to be able to do this:

```
Sub testpastertf()
    Dim MyData As DataObject
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim strSelectionB() As Byte
    
    str = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252 TT\sub 0\f1\lang1033\_\f2\lang18441 1\nosupersub\par}"

    ReDim strSelectionB(0 To Len(str)) As Byte
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
      strSelectionB(i - 1) = Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))
    Next
    strSelectionB(Len(str)) = 0
    Set MyData = New DataObject
        
    mydata.SetText strSelectionB, "Rich Text Format"
    mydata.PutInClipboard
    
    ' Or you can just Selection.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, Placement:= _
        wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

However, that only works because the RTF we have used only contains characters that would occupy one byte in Unicode UTF8 format. OTTOMH I can't remember what using ansicp1252 implies as far as that's concerned, but if you can have characters in your RTF that can't be encoded as a single byte, I think your code would actually need to do more work translating 16-bit characters into the byte array.

[Additional point from comments] When trying to copy HTML chunks, you have to provide a header with some offsets - I would have a good look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/) and the documents linked from there).

Comment: Much simpler but I've seen so many times where using the DataObject approach has not worked (Win10 32-bit Excel) - I just get "??" in the clipboard.

Comment: I agree - where it works then it's much more straightforward.

Comment: Tested. This works like a charm! On a separate note, Any idea how could do the same using HTML code rather than RTF? Perhaps a simpler option to achieve the same thing on my end.

Comment: Hi @slightlysnarky, I have looked into that thread and added a function to include the HTML elements. This works like a charm as usual! I uploaded the code in the function shown in the answer below (see `addHTMLWraper` function) which I adapted to VBA.