# Pasting HTML into Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to paste 6000 HTML strings into Word as formatted using VBA. I can do this if I insert an HTML file, but would rather do this with passing a string.
This is the sample HTML I'm using:

```
<html><body>normal <b>bold</b><br></body></html>
```

I can get this to work:

```
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="html test file.htm"
```

Result: normal **bold** (this is what I want).

But not this (with the above HTML in the clipboard):

```
ActiveDocument.Range.PasteSpecial ,,,,WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML
```

With the later, I get error 5342 "the specified data type is unavailable".

- In a perfect world, I can just pass a string.
- In an imperfect world, I can copy the HTML to the clipboard, then copy the clipboard into Word.
- In a sucky world, I can write the HTML to a text file, then insert that file into Word (repeat 6000 times).
  Even though this is a one off project, I'd rather learn the efficient way to do this, so any help would be appreciated.
  In case it's not clear, this is raw HTML from a database, not copying an already formatted page.
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716400/injecting-rtf-code-in-the-clipboard-to-paste-into-ms-word-as-rtf-text-via-a-vba/63721540?noredirect=1#comment112698372_63721540 lengthy but works well for setting HTML clipboard content.

Comment: ...just tried that out, and it should be fine for your use case.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Small test worked great. It is lengthy, but will make a nice library addition. Put it down as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted by GMCB (accepted answer) here will do what you want, based on some short testing:

[Injecting RTF code in the Clipboard to paste into MS Word as RTF text via a VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716400/injecting-rtf-code-in-the-clipboard-to-paste-into-ms-word-as-rtf-text-via-a-vba/63721540?noredirect=1#comment112698372_63721540)

The main focus of that post is putting RTF-format text into the clipboard, but it also covers populating HTML-format.