# How can I Move Access Richtext (HTML format) to PowerPoint TextFrame and retain the formatting?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ms-access-2016, richtext

I am building a Powerpoint Presentation using VBA code in an Access database.  I need to be able to paste text that users have typed into an Access RichText Textbox into a Powerpoint slide TextFrame.  I have tried numerous approaches from posts, none of which work.

Most of what I have tried either has the ....  show up in the text or I get an *The specified value is out of range* error.

I have solved the problem in Word using the write to temp file, insert file into Word, but Powerpoint does not seem to have the needed methods. (At least everything I tried failed, or does not give the desired result.)

I would like to make this code work:

```vb
Public Sub WriteHTMLtoPowerPoint_Debug(strHTMLText As String, pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape)
    ' strHTML is Access Rich text with <Html> .... </HTML> wrapper
    
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    
    DataObj.SetText strHTMLText
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
    
    ' The Paste, PasteSpecial, TextFrame, TextFrame2 all cause the  error: The specified value is out of range.
    ' HasTextFrame is true, HasText is true.  Tried deleting text then pasting.
    ' Also tried adding " " as text, then pasting.
    ' No difference between TextRange and TextRange2.  Same error.
    ' pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML, msoFalse, , , , msoFalse
    pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, DisplayAsIcon:=msoFalse, link:=msoFalse
    
    ' Same error.  Tried several variations. None worked.
    ' Including without (), and named parameters, DataType:=msoClipboardFormatHTML, etc.
    'pptShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.PasteSpecial (msoClipboardFormatHTML)
    
Proc_Exit:
   On Error Resume Next
   Set DataObj = Nothing

   Exit Sub

Proc_Err:
    LogError Err.Number, Err.Description, mcModuleName, "WriteHTMLtoPowerPoint", vbNullString, gcGENERAL_ERROR, False
    Resume Proc_Exit
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Does any body have a working solution to this task?  Do you see an error in my code?

Comment: Would help to include actual example(s) of the text you want to be able to copy, so that anyone who wanted to try this out can test.

Comment: See discussion here around setting different clipboard formats using the Windows API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716400/injecting-rtf-code-in-the-clipboard-to-paste-into-ms-word-as-rtf-text-via-a-vba

Comment: ```<HTML><div align=center>(U) Concept Approval Briefing for </div>

<div align=center>MISTIC DEVELOPER TEST</div>

<div align=center>[Project Date]</div></HTML>```

Comment: Tim,  I looked at the clipboard link.  I had found that thread when I was working on moving formatted text to word.  That was when I discovered Access RichText is HTML. (I have to add the <HTML> ... </HTML> wrapper via code. That is not in the Access data).  It does not follow the RTF Standard, which is why the task get's Complicated. 

I solved the problem in word by using  another technique I found somewhere on Stackoverflow, copy html to a temp file, then use ```wDoc.Application.selection.InsertFile tempHtmlFile, , False``` to insert it.  I was unable to make that work in PPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me using the clipboard class from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63735992/478884

```vb
Sub TestHtmlPaste()
    
    Dim myClipboard As New vbaClipboard
    Dim sRTF As String, HTML As String
    Dim ppApp As Object
    
    'HTML = "Hello <span style='color:#F00'>world</span>"
    HTML = "<div align=center>(U) Concept Approval Briefing" & _
          "for </div>  <div align=center>MISTIC DEVELOPER TEST</div>" & _
          "<div align=center>[Project Date]</div>"
    
    myClipboard.SetClipboardText HTML, "HTML Format"
    
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "powerpoint.application") 'attach to running PPT
    ppApp.activepresentation.slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste
    
End Sub
```

Comment: A thousand thanks!!!  Using the clipboard link and your test got be going.  I had tried two or three different Clipboard approaches that did not work.  Yours did.  WIth your clipboard class I was also able to make it work with the Shape and PasteSpecial.

Comment: That fixed the errors, but the formatting information is stripped out.  (Didn't realize it when I first tested.).  I can cut and paste manually and the formatting is included.  

Any suggestions on getting the formatting to be passed on as well?

Comment: Ant specific formatting being lost? The commented-out html in my answer worked fine for me.

Comment: The red in this HTML does not show up:  <div align=center>(U) Concept<font color=red> Approval Briefing</font> for </div>

Comment: The red in your sample using span style does work:<span style='color:#F00'>

Comment: From what I can tell, font is deprecated, but Access still uses it for what they call RTF.  I may have to write a parser, sigh......